# Yocto recipe : how to install in specific folder

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, recipe

I have created a Yocto recipe for my program.
What are the default folders that are building image from recipe ?
At the time of building image, I want to move my files to another folder like "/opt/xyz".

Should I simply do "mv" or is there any other options?

Comment: Can you please explain more what you try to accomplish? Do you want to move files inside or outside of the final yocto image?

Comment: Why don't you simply have your recipe install its files in the correct location (i.e. `/opt/xyz`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you want to copy your compiled program to a folder such as `${bindir}`:

> Quote from Yocto ref-manual 1.1:
> When specifying paths as part of the CONFFILES variable, it is good practice to use appropriate path variables. For example, ${sysconfdir} rather than /etc or ${bindir} rather than /usr/bin. You can find a list of these variables at the top of the meta/conf/bitbake.conf file in the [Source Directory](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#source-directory).

You can copy files from your working directory to any directory in the target filesystem. See the [hello-world example](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.1/poky-ref-manual/poky-ref-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-addpkg-singlec) for instance (note that the example is taken from the 1.1 reference manual, but I haven't found it yet in the newer version):

```
 DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld application"
 SECTION = "examples"
 LICENSE = "MIT"
 LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
 PR = "r0"

 SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"

 S = "${WORKDIR}"

 do_compile() {
    ${CC} helloworld.c -o helloworld
 }

 do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
 }

 FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}"
```

In this example, the `helloworld` binary would be copied to `/usr/bin` on your image (could be `/opt` too, see Source Directory for the variable definition).
Adjust FILES_${PN} var for `${sysconfdir} ${bindir} ${datadir} ${libdir}` directories.

Answer (score 5):

```
do_install(){
  install -d ${D}{base_prefix}/opt/xyz/          
  install -m ${WORKDIR}/yourbinary    ${D}${base_prefix}/opt/xyz/
}

FILES_${PN} = "${base_prefix}/opt/*"
```

above 
1st line creates the dir in imagedir in that opt/xvz/

2nd line copy your binary to opt/xyz/dir

3rd line use to copy of your opt/xyz/binary to yocto rootfs.